# How to set up key bindings for Powershell on Arch Linux?

Tags: powershell, arch-linux

I live on Arch Linux (Manjaro) but I'm starting to learn Powershell. I've installed powershell from the AUR with `yay -S powershell`. However, when using powershell (`pwsh`), I've found that the key bindings aren't working. Pressing up/down doesn't go through the command history, and pressing `TAB` and `ctrl-space` don't trigger tab-completion.

I'm using alacritty with zsh. However, I've also tested it with `xterm pwsh` and the same problem is there, so I believe the terminal emulator and parent shell are *not* the cause, and that I need to configure the key bindings myself.

How do I configure the basic powershell key bindings?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell key bindings are controlled by the `PSReadLine` module that ships with it. The module provides various features such as syntax coloring, a good multi-line experience, history and more (see: https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine).

What you are looking for are the key handlers:

```
PS> Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function Complete
```

Make sure to check their documentation for a full overview of the supported configuration parameters:

```
PS> help about_PSReadLine
# Or list the key current handlers and options:
PS> Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler
PS> Get-PSReadLineOption
```

You can find an example configuration in their git repository: https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/blob/master/PSReadLine/SamplePSReadLineProfile.ps1. All PSReadline customizations need to be added to your PowerShell profile to persist them across sessions:

```
PS> echo $PROFILE
/Users/megamorf/.config/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

---

Here's what I typically have in my PowerShell profile:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Emacs -BellStyle None
Set-PSReadLineOption -HistorySearchCursorMovesToEnd

Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function MenuComplete
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key UpArrow -Function HistorySearchBackward
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key DownArrow -Function HistorySearchForward

Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key Ctrl+Shift+P `
    -BriefDescription CopyPathToClipboard `
    -LongDescription "Copies the current path to the clipboard" `
    -ScriptBlock { (Resolve-Path -LiteralPath $pwd).ProviderPath.Trim() | Set-Clipboard }
```